# Is there a 2-point clip in Blender?

Tags: edit-mode

I'd like to cut a mesh by giving two points (in order to form a line). For example, I would be able to easily cut the mesh in the picture below (which is an arch) instead of *roughly* bringing each vertex to the hypothetical diagonal line.

[image: 2 point clip example]

Am I missing the tool or are there similar ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: Use the knife tool. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Knife_Subdivide

Comment: see also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8955/cut-straight-lines-with-knife-tool/8957#8957 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6889/how-to-cut-a-mesh-by-specifying-the-angle/6911#6911 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object/7933#7933

Comment: Awesome! I think this is a duplicate then.

Comment: @cegaton Uhm there is a problem, though. Since it doesn't snap to grid, I can't really make precise cuts. Any solution?

Comment: there are different ways to constrain the cut by pressing k and then pressing E, Ctrl, C or Z read the documentation

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8955/599

Comment: @cegaton I did, but there's no snap-to-grid function.